# Convert array into a string ready ajax data filter using php

Tags: php

Can the following array be converted into the string below...

```
$eventsfilters = array(
    'language' => $languagePath,
    'page' => 1, 
    'limit' => 9, 
    'start_date' => time()
);
```

into this:

```
$ajax_filter = "'language': '" . $languagePath . "', 'page': 1, 'limit': 9, 'start_date': " . time();
```

This will then go into an ajax data filter.

Comment: Yes, yes it can. What have you tried?

Comment: `json_encode()` perhaps?

Comment: php runs on the server, js on the client. Why would you use php fo this purpose?

Comment: I've tried imploding the array but that just gives me the values, i need the keys aswell.

Comment: That string looks like a malformed JSON string. What is interpreting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with below code :

```html
$eventsfilters = array(
    'language' => "sdfsd",
    'page' => 1, 
    'limit' => 9, 
    'start_date' => time()
);

foreach($eventsfilters as $key => $val){
    $arr[] = "'$key':".$val; 
}

$arr = implode(",", $arr);

echo $arr;
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I'm after. Should have known to loop through the array to then implode it :/

Comment: @RobMorris : IF you want comma separated value from array then you can used implode function. In your case you need key as well so need to build new array from given array then implode it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is going through an AJAX filter it will probably need to be in a JSON format. The string you posted is not valid json. It is best to just pass the array into [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$ajax_filter = json_encode($eventsfilters);
```

Which would return something like this:

```
{"language":"languagePath","page":1,"limit":9,"start_date":1412241074}
```